# Deploying small sprinboot app jar to App Engine billed for high network usage

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, billing

I am seeking assistance regarding the charges incurred while deploying my Spring Boot microservice application with just 1 endpoint that prints if isActive to Google App Engine for the first time. The application, once compiled, weighs approximately 20 MB, and I deployed it using the `gcloud app deploy service.jar command. After the deployment process was complete, I noticed that my Google Cloud payment account had been charged for "Networking Traffic Egress GCP Replication within Northern America Cloud Storage." Specifically, the charge for the use of 1.1 GB. I am reaching out to inquire whether there is an explanation for these charges and if there are any steps I can take to prevent or minimize such charges in the future.

Noticed that multiple container images where created on cloud storage but I would assume that was internal network traffic.

Comment: 1.1 GB is a small amount of traffic on the Internet. If you make a service public, there are thousands of bots and hackers that will poke and prod your endpoint. There is nothing you can do to prevent that short of enabling authorization. To know what kind of traffic, review the logs.

Comment: @JohnHanley the app remained live for about 1 hour and checking our logs it didnt received traffic on any of its endpoints. Most likely seem like traffic while deploying and containerazing the jar

Comment: Without details on what you deployed, 1 GB might be reasonable for Cloud Storage usage. Edit your post so that enough details are provided so that a fact-based answer can be generated. Otherwise, delete the question if you feel an answer is no longer necessary

Comment: @JohnHanley I just added to the description that the spring boot app just had 1 endpoint to check the app was up and running, I'm a bit concerned that trying to use the free tier of app engine I'm being charded, as stated earlier there was no incoming traffic. Seems that all this egress traffic from cloud storage was during the deployment process but 1gb(egress traffic) vs 20mb(apps jar size) seems incredible

Comment: The bucket that is being used for App Engine artifacts is a multi-region bucket. You are charged for replication traffic. [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#inter-region-replication)

Comment: Without more details, I don't know what generated the 1.1 GB of traffic. When I first commented, I missed the wording of the message `Networking Traffic Egress GCP Replication within Northern America Cloud Storage` which clearly tells you what the traffic is for. Did you do multiple builds/deployments? Does your app download lots of files during the build process? The final result may be 20 MB but the interim files might be much larger. You mention `SpringBoot`. Java is not the smallest of languages.

Comment: I agree that building a spring boot application might not be a light process, however that's why I did the compilation and created the uber jar that was deployed locally (no usage of cloud build). I did just 1 deployment at that timeand have done individual test per day to check if using different deployment processes(specifying instance type, min instances, using cloud build instad of jar deployment) result in a "free" deployment however all of them end in a very similar usage of the Network egress traffic. @JohnHanley